# Verificar se algum input file foi alterado

Tags: jquery

Meu formulário possui vários inputs assim:

```
<input type="file" name="imagem_file[]" class="form-control">

<button id="btnProdutoImagem" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Cadastrar</button>
```

E meu Jquery verifica se o input foi alterado  assim:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnProdutoImagem").on('click', function(){

        var target = $("input[name='imagem_file[]:first']").val();

        if (target.length == 0) {
          console.log('Nenhum arquivo selecionado.');
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Porém assim funciona apenas se o primeiro input file for alterado, se seleciono o segundo o Jquery não identifica, como identificar se qualquer um foi alterado e validar?

Se deixo apenas assim:

```
var target = $("input[name='imagem_file[]']").val();
```

O Jquery não valida também.

Comment: acredito que [] no nome do input não seja algo válido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com `:first` você está selecionando apenas o primeiro.

Para verificar todos você precisa percorrer os campos para ver se algum foi preenchido. Para isso pode usar `.each`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnProdutoImagem").on('click', function(){

        var target = $("input[name='imagem_file[]']");
        var vazio = true;
        
        target.each(function(i,e){
           if($(e).val()){
              vazio = false;
           }
        });

        if(vazio){
             console.log('Nenhum arquivo selecionado.');
        }

    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="imagem_file[]" class="form-control">
<br>
<input type="file" name="imagem_file[]" class="form-control">
<br>
<input type="file" name="imagem_file[]" class="form-control">
<br>
<button id="btnProdutoImagem" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Cadastrar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não consegue detectar as alterações no input com o evento change?

```
<input id="input-file" type="file" name="imagem_file[]" class="form-control">

<button id="btnProdutoImagem" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Cadastrar</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#input-file").on('change', function(){

          alert('Meu arquivo mudou, devo fazer alguma coisa...');

    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: A verificação seria somente no enviar do formulário, por isso não, até poderia ter feito assim, mas não para a condição do que estou desenvolvendo. Obrigado!